# Why does Magento 2.1.2 cron:run gives Undefined index: jobs?

Tags: magento2, cron

When running:

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

I get:

```
[Exception]                                                                  
  Notice: Undefined index: jobs in /home/ubuntu/repo/project/vendor/magento/
               module-cron/Model/Config/Converter/Db.php on line 39
```

Comment: What does cron log says?

Comment: There is an error in `update.log`: `setup-cron.ERROR: Database 'my-db' does not exist or specified database server user does not have privileges to access this database.`

Comment: So issue was that the data migration tool added cron entries at the wrong level: so did `delete from core_config_data where path like 'crontab/jobs%';` https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/Error-when-running-cron-job-Undefined-index-jobs/td-p/35816

Comment: Fixed the first issue but now running `php /var/www/shootingstuff/update/cron.php` gives `PHP Warning:  require_once(/dir/update/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /dir/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 15
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '/dir/update/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /dir/update/app/bootstrap.php on line 15`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

In my case it was caused by some cron jobs migrated from Magento 1, in `core_config_data`.
Magento 2 expects the format to be `crontab/{groupname}/jobs/{code}`, while the imported ones miss the group name (i.e. default).
If that is your case you might want to delete the wrong entries in `core_config_data`, or update them to map the new cron jobs.

Comment: You might need to remove all crontab entries from `core_config_data` table and then run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

Comment: `bin/magento ca:fl config` was enough for me

Comment: You're right! It's really there in core_config_data since this site that I'm working was migrated before from M1 to M2.1, Thanks again!

Comment: Deleted 202 entries :) ```DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'crontab/%' AND path NOT LIKE 'crontab/default%' AND config_id > 0``` I needed last part `AND config_id > 0` because of safe mode.

Comment: Thanks @DamodarBashyal for sharing query.

Answer (score 7):

I have the same error. This is the error when migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. So I fixed it by remove all rows have "path" start by "crobtab" in table "core_config_data".

Then run this:
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

And error fixed. Magento 2 will generate all cronjobs again.

Comment: thanks it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

As rcason said: this issue is due to migration from Magento 1 to Magento 2. After removing from "core _config_data" all the values that starts with crontab/default... (under Config Path) the problem is solved, and M2 cron jobs now run with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the wrong format of cron configuration in database.
Try cleanup `cron_schedule` table and try run cron again.

Also please check cron setting in system configuration.

Comment: There is nothing in `cron_schedule`

Answer (score 1):

**Please test in dev environment first!**

**Always backup your database before trying out new stuff!**

The error I stumbled upon was:

```
Exception #0 (Exception): Warning: Undefined array key "jobs" in ./vendor/magento/module-cron/Model/Config/Converter/Db.php on line 39
```

I had to combine from answers and comments, so the SQL that worked for me was:

```
truncate cron_schedule;
DELETE FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE 'crontab/%';
```

then

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento cache:clean
```