# Magento2 how to check if cronjobs are correctly set?

Tags: magento2, crontab

I'm pretty sure my cronjobs doesn't work properly. All catalog rules that I created are resetting every day. I checked the `cron_schedule` table in my db and its empty. Is there a way to test or check if the jobs are well executed?

According to the Magento 2 documentation, I have created a crontab like the following:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/prod/var/log/magento.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/update/cron.php >> /var/www/prod/var/log/update.cron.log
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/prod/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

When I search for "How to create a cronjob for M2", I find a lot of answers. For example, some adds the `php.ini` path or `*/1` for schedule.

```
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini /var/www/prod/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/prod/var/log/magento.cron.log
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini /var/www/prod/update/cron.php >> /var/www/prod/var/log/update.cron.log
*/1 * * * * /usr/bin/php -c /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini /var/www/prod/bin/magento setup:cron:run >> /var/www/prod/var/log/setup.cron.log
```

Which one should I use?

Comment: You need to match these settings with settings in your admin configuration. Also 1 minute is not enough to complete the task before the next one begins so it will never finish. 5 minutes at least and i recommend 10 min

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am going to explain three different ways to test if your cronjobs are working properly.

### First of all

Magento creates three log files, which are `var/log/magento.cron.log`, `var/log/update.cron.log` and `var/log/setup.cron.log`. You can watch these log files.

### Secondly

You should see some input with the following SQL query: `select * from cron_schedule`. It keeps track of each cron job, when it is run, when it is finished if it is finished.

### Finally

You can run the following commands on your command line, and see if they are running properly without any error.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule"
/usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/update/cron.php
/usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

## About the cronjob entries

To your second question (*Which one should I use?*), the first and the second approach almost the same. The only difference is that you are explicitly defining the `php.ini` in the second one. In my opinion, the `php.ini` file for cronjobs and for the web should be the same. (*Note that `*/1` and `*` is the same thing.*)

> To avoid issues during installation and upgrade, we strongly recommend you apply the same PHP settings to both the PHP command-line configuration and to the PHP web server plug-in’s configuration. For more information, see Required PHP settings. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Comment: I try this command : /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" and result is : Notice: Undefined index: jobs in /var/www/prod/vendor/magento/module-cron/Model/Config/Converter/Db.php on line 39
Also try : /usr/bin/php /var/www/prod/update/cron.php and result : Cron readiness check failure! Found non-writable paths:  /var/www/prod/ISSUE_TEMPLATE.md [] [] in the update.log

Comment: You might wanna look at this question, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/145349/why-does-magento-2-1-2-cronrun-gives-undefined-index-jobs

Comment: thanks, my M2 store come from a M1.7 with migration tools and it seems these tools added entries from M1 in the core_config_data table so the new config as no access to the new db.

Comment: solved. just run "delete from core_config_data where path like 'crontab/jobs%';" and now my cron_schedule table has entries. Thanks a lot