# Magento 2 I want to run below command line for every minutes

Tags: magento2, cron, cli

I'm using `Magento 2.3`, Here when create bulk action from product grid schedule not started and updated. 
I got solution for the above issue when I run this command above issue fixed. So I want to run this command or every minutes,

```
php bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update --max-messages=20
```

Is there any way to run this command pro-grammatically from my controller?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use crontab there.

Comment: No, I don't know how to run the cron job using this command.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento2 how to check if cronjobs are correctly set?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/199489/magento2-how-to-check-if-cronjobs-are-correctly-set)

Answer (score 2):

Finally I got solution. ***Just I enabled cron_consumers_runner from app/etc/env.php***. Default cron_consumers_runner is false, Just i changed true.

'cron_consumers_runner' => [
'**cron_run' => true**,
        'max_messages' => 10000,
        'consumers' => [
        ]
    ],

Answer (score 0):

1. Connect to your web server using ssh
2. Locate your current PHP CLI path by run command:

   which php

On my ubuntu server, the output is:

```
/usr/bin/php
```

3. Open crontab setting by run command:

   crontab -e

The crontab is just like a text file, every line is a job will run with a schedule.
For example:

```
The part 45 3 * * * is time schedule. That says the script will run at 3:45 every day. You can visit https://crontab.guru/ to learn about the time schedule, and set your own time.
```

4. When you're done setting the cron, just hit **ESC** and **wq** to save your cron just like a text file.